# Adapting D3 to PowerBI D3 Visual

Tags: d3.js, powerbi, data-visualization

I am trying to adapt some code, in order to make it work in PowerBI. Although i am pretty sure i know where the problem is (the function), i can't figure it out.

I followed this tutorial https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5273/how-to-render-d3js-custom-charts-in-power-bi-desktop/

```
-added pbi.height and pbi.width
-removed .append("svg") from svg var
-tried messing with the function by adding pbi.dsv
-i have a pbi object with 2 columns and 2 values
-i also have the css in place
```

Original code: https://codepen.io/herudea/pen/YpEeRW

```
var width = pbi.width,
    height = pbi.height,
    twoPi = 2 * Math.PI,
    progress = 0,
    allocated = "completed",
    total = "total",
    formatPercent = d3.format(".0%");

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .startAngle(0)
    .innerRadius(58)
    .outerRadius(66);

var svg = d3.select("#docsChart")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var meter = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "funds-allocated-meter");

meter.append("path")
    .attr("class", "background")
    .attr("d", arc.endAngle(twoPi));

var foreground = meter.append("path")
    .attr("class", "foreground");

var percentComplete = meter.append("text")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("class", "percent-complete")
    .attr("dy", "0em");

var description = meter.append("text")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("class", "description")
    .attr("dy", "2.3em")
    .text("Total Complete");

var i = d3.interpolate(progress, allocated / total);

 d3.transition().duration(1000).tween("progress", function() {
  return   function(t) {
    progress = i(t);
    foreground.attr("d", arc.endAngle(twoPi * progress));
    percentComplete.text(formatPercent(progress));
  };
});
```

I expect to have a working gauge based on the created pbi object.

Comment: Just realised, asigning the column name to "allocated" and "total" variables is not the smartest idea. However it is not working even if i assign integers to them.